# ¿Cómo eliminar diferentes terminaciones de palabras sin afectar los ya sustituidos?

Tags: regex, r

Lo que deseo es que cuando ponga el primer `gsub` elimine `"SO"` si le antecede una `"O"` y esté al final de la palabra.
Ejemplo: `POSO PASO --> PO PASO`.

Pero después eliminar con otro `gsub` solo las `"O"` al final de la palabra sin afectar las palabras a las que ya se les elimino las letras `"SO"`.
Ejemplo: `PO PASO --> PO PAS`

```
 data <- c("CASOSO"," ARBOSO","TOCO","POCO","LEJOS")  

 data <- gsub("SO\\b","",data)
 data <- gsub("O\\b","",data)
```

Resultado:

```
 [1] "CAS"      " ARB" "TOC"      "POC"  "LEJO"
```

mi resultado esperado es este:

```
[1] "CASO"      " ARBO" "TOC"      "POC"  "LEJOS"
```

Comment: Que tal si invierte el orden de eliminación primero retira las "O" y luego las "S"

Comment: hola gracias por contestar pero si invierto ya no encontraría SO al final

Comment: Leo que es SO, la letra común para todas según el ejemplo es O. Lo sencillo sería eliminarla primero de todas las palabras, la siguiente que no quiere es la S como el caso de ARBOS, esto dejaría tal como quiere el resultado final ARBO.

Comment: hola ya lo he intentado el problema persiste por que si hay otra palabra en el vector como Ejemplo : LEJOS eliminaria la "S" y así quedaria     LEJO.                sin que hubiera terminado en SO

Comment: Bien que actualizará el ejemplo porque fue confuso al comienzo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que no colisionen diferentes reemplazos, se debe hacer con una única expresión regular. Entonces, si la palabra termina en:

- `OSO`, reemplazar por `"O"`, o en
- `O`, reemplazar por `""`.

Regex:

```
(O)SO\b|O\b
```

Reemplazando por:

```
\1
```

- Estamos usando un *OR* (alternancia) con `|` para incluir ambas opciones.
- En la primera opción, usamos un grupo (paréntesis) en la `O` para que si coincide, se incluya esa `O` en el resultado al reemplazar por `\1`.

---

Sin embargo, podemos simplificarlo aún más uniéndolo como:

```
O(?:S(O))?\b
```

Reemplazando por:

```
\1
```

- `(?:`…`)` es un grupo sin captura, que nos permite cuantificar esa parte con `?` para hacerla opcional

Código:

```
data <- c("CASOSO"," ARBOSO","TOCO","POCO","LEJOS")  
gsub("O(?:S(O))?\\b", "\\1", data, perl=TRUE)
```

Resultado:

```
[1] "CASO"  " ARBO" "TOC"   "POC"   "LEJOS"
```

Demo:

https://ideone.com/11654A

Comment: Excelente, cierran todos los casos que comentó el OP

Comment: Gran respuesta te agradezco mucho @Mariano ya que me tenia loco encontrar solucion

Comment: Gracias también a ti @Patricio Moracho